# Displaying error message in login page after login failure - If condition is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am quite new to web development.
I have a login.jsp and a filter servlet .
In case of unsuccessful login, the message has to be displayed on the same page.

### Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="home">
       <header class="heading">
            <label class="headfont">Digital Market Place</label>
      </header>

    <form action="./servlet1" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="login">
            <label class="loginMsg">Log in to your seller account</label>
        </div>
            <div class="input">
                UserName: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
                <br>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="loginbtn">Log In</button>

            <%
            out.println(request.getAttribute("loginResult"));

                if(request.getAttribute("loginResult") != null && "true".equals(request.getAttribute("loginResult"))) {
                    out.println("inide if");


            %>
            <p style="color: red">Login Failed. Please try again.</p> 
            <%
            }

        %>
        <div class="signup">
                <label class="signMsg">Don&#039t have a seller account?</label>
                <span style="white-space:nowrap;padding-left: 20px;"><a title="register" href="registration.jsp"> Sign up now</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And my filter servlet is as given below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class MyFilter implements Filter{

FilterConfig filterConfig;

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    setFilterConfig(arg0);
}


public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig config) {
    this.filterConfig = config;
}

public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
    return filterConfig; 
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(getFilterConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/conf/user.conf"));
    if(username.equals(properties.getProperty("username")) && password.equals(properties.getProperty("password"))){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);//sends request to next resource
    }
    else    {
        request.setAttribute("loginResult", true);

        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

The request.getAttribute("loginResult") prints "true" on unsuccesful login. 
But it seems the control is not going inisde the if condition.

Can any one please help

Comment: `"true".equals(request.getAttribute("loginResult").toString())` try this one. because `request.getAttribute("loginResult")` will return `Object` type value, you need to typecast to String.

Comment: Try putting some debugging statements to see the code flow and values or debug in case if you are using an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is because `request.getAttribute(String arg)` will return `Object type` value. and you are calling `equals` method to compare with `String` object so it will always return `false`.

You need to use `toString()` method to change the value to `String`

change your code as

```
 if(request.getAttribute("loginResult") != null && "true".equals(request.getAttribute("loginResult").toString())) {
                out.println("inide if");
```

Comment: @user1407668 if it was helpful then you can mark it as answer, it will be helpful for others also.